# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running via Eclipse

Tags: java, runtime-error

I get the following error messages when attempting to run my program via Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/JavaVersion
at lemmini.LemminiFrame.main(LemminiFrame.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

The project has all necessary dependencies loaded and there are now 0 errors in the code (there are some warnings though).

Ideas welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, a friend of mine tried running exactly the same code/setup on his copy of Eclipse and the program ran, so there must be something wrong with Java on my system (he's on Windows, I'm on macOS). I have updated both the JDK and the JRE... no dice. Really stuck here guys, I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that the issues I've been experiencing are all to do with the dependencies. I loaded them into a folder called 'dependencies' within the project folders (alongside 'src') and then imported them from there via Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries (then choose Classpath>Add JARs)

I can now run the program within Eclipse, but can't run it as an executable .jar

The journey continues...